# Visual Studio 2013 (XAML?) Designer crash on all Windows Phone projects even after aquiring developer license

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, crash, designer

My designer started to crash, even on clean projects. The error message is as follows:

```
System.Exception
Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.

Windows cannot install package App.afbb198c1.a50af.a4b90.aa065.a08732a9e43b0 because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 0.0.0.0 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug published by any publisher to install. Provide the framework along with this package.
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.
<>c__DisplayClassa`1.
    <StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

renewing the `project->store->developer license` does not help. What can be done about this?

There is no additional information in the Event Log about any of the happenings.

Comment: are you trying to install any kind of package?

Comment: not that I am aware of, how do I check that?

Comment: right click on your solution, and select the option called Manage Nuget Packages for Solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing some packages, you need to look into Nuget and see what packages are missing. Or with NuGet you can restore all packages in the solution using the command line.

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```

Or Reinstall all packages in ALL PROJECTS of the current solution:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

Reinstall all packages in SPECIFIC PROJECT of the current solution

```
Update-Package -ProjectName 'YourProjectNameGoesHere' -Reinstall
```